# accessing a field from json django

Tags: django

```
 data1 = serializers.serialize( "python", members)
    print data1[0]


{'pk': 4L, 'model': u'logic.member', 'fields': {'profile': 3L, 'name': u'1', 'title': u'Mr', 'dob': datetime.date(1983, 1, 1), 'lastname': u'jkjk', 'redressno': u'jdsfsfkj', 'gender': u'm'}}
```

**how can i access the fields of this json object**

if i do

```
  print data1[0].fields
```

getting an erro

```
  'dict' object has no attribute 'fields'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are dictionary keys, not attributes.

```
data1[0]['fields']['profile']
data1[0]['fields']['name']
```

etc

Comment: i want to put fields in seperate array how can i do that , can u tell here update in answer or should i enter new question for it ?

Comment: added a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140505/making-seperate-array-from-existing-json-django