# making separate array from existing json django

Tags: django

I have this array of JSON:

```
[{'pk': 4L, 'model': u'logic.member', 'fields': {'profile': 3L, 'name': u'1', 'title': u'Mr', 'dob': datetime.date(1983, 1, 1), 'lastname': u'jkjk', 'redressno': u'jdsfsfkj', 'gender': u'm'}}, {'pk': 5L, 'model': u'logic.member', 'fields': {'profile': 3L, 'name': u'2', 'title': u'Mr', 'dob': datetime.date(1983, 1, 1), 'lastname': u'jkjk', 'redressno': u'jdsfsfkj', 'gender': u'm'}}]
```

I want to make separate array of JSON for only `fields` property.

What I tried is:

```
memarr=[] 

       for index,a in data1:
          print index
          print a
          memarr[index]=a[index].fields
```

And it is giving an error of:

```
too many values to unpack
```

Please correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, data1 is a list, so you can't unpack it into 2 variables.

If you want the index, you have to use something like `enumerate`.

Second, you can't assign to a list via indexing if the key doesn't exist. You have to append or use another valid list insert method.

Third, `a[index].fields` doesn't really make sense - there is no key in `a` that would be associated with an integer index and `fields` is not an attribute.

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
memarr = []
for index, a in enumerate(data1):
    memarr.append(a['fields'])
```

Answer (score 0):

So many things wrong with that snippet...

Anyway:

```
memarr = [a['fields'] for a in data]
```